# Determining if results exist with VBA ODBC driver for MySQL

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, odbc

I'm using the ODBC mysql driver in Excel VBA to query a database.

There is an issue where the `.recordCount` property always seems to return -1, whether the result contains data or not.

How can I check if the query has returned any data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is typical for DAO recordsets of type dbOpenDynaset.

The count represents the number of records accessed so far. A `.MoveLast` is the correct approach if you need the real count.

```
rs.Movelast
rs.RecordCount
```

**AND/OR,**

Try to set `CursorLocation` property of your record set to `adUseClient` (before opening the recordset). This might fix the problem. It might also fix the problem of recordcount showing up as -1.

Comment: I get an error saying "Rowset does not support fetching backward"